# how to synchronize clocks between 2 peers for a p2p game

Tags: synchronization, clock, p2p

I have a p2p game.

I'm having a problem where the players aren't playing the game at exactly the same time.

the clocks on different computers are off by literally seconds!

the best solution I came up with is sending a ping asking about their local time, and dividing by 2, to approximate when they sent it. but obviously this isn't perfect.

I need the clocks to be synced within a couple milliseconds. is there a more clever way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

have the client grab their system time and use that for any areas that need time displayed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).